# Uploading multiple CSVs from local source to GBQ using command line

Tags: bash, command-line, sdk, google-bigquery, command-prompt

I'm putting together a for loop on Google Cloud SDK Shell that will upload every CSV from the current directory (on my local computer) to a separate Google BigQuery table, all in the same dataset. Also, I want the created tables in GBQ to have the same name of their corresponding CSV files (except the .csv part).

I was actually able to do all that using the following command line, expect that it appends all CSVs in the same table not in separate tables.

`for %d in (*.csv); do set var1=%d & bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV "DatasetName.%var1:~0,-5%" %d`

Hint: it seems to me that the variable "var1" gets updated in each loop, but the bq load function doesn't use the updated values, it keeps the same original value until the loop ends regardless.

Current Output: 
[image]

Comment: Do the tables have the same schema ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I was not able to reproduce a BigQuery load from my local environment to BigQuery. I was capable to reproduce this case uploading *.csv* files from Google Shell to BigQuery.

I tried running your code but my attempts were unsuccessful. Thus, I created the following bash script to map and upload all the *.csv* files to BigQuery with a bq load command, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting the script"
for i in *.csv;
do
        echo ${i%.csv} " loading";
        bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV project_id:dataset.Table_${i%.csv} ./$i;
        echo ${i%.csv} " was loaded"
done
```

Notice that, the script maps only the *.csv* files within the directory it is located. Also, ***${i%.csv}*** returns only the filename without the extension, which is used to name the destination table. On the other hand, ***$i*** returns the whole filename including the *.csv*, so it is used to point to the source file in the *bq load command*.

About the ***bq command***, the **[--autodetect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#loading_data_using_schema_auto-detection)** flag was used in order to auto detect the schema of each table.

Furthermore, since this load job is from a local data source, it is necessary to specify the project id in the destination's table path, here: ***project_id:dataset.Table_${i%.csv}***.

As a bonus information, you can also upload you data to a Google Cloud Bucket and upload all the files to BigQuery using [wild cards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#load-wildcards), [Python script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) with a loop or [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/join-streaming-data-with-sql)( streaming or batch) depending on you needs.

Comment: Hi Alexandre. I wonder if I could trouble you to refrain from adding "hope this helps" and other such pleasantries to your answers? Volunteer editors remove these because they are conversational, and are not the technical writing we try to aim for. Also, since no-one posts an answer hoping it doesn't help, it is surely rather redundant.

Comment: @Alexandre Moraes..  could you please help on this.. #!/bin/bash

for filelocation in $(gsutil ls gs://test-bucket-03/test/CM/*.csv | sed 's/ //g')
do
echo "file location :" $filelocation
filename=$(basename "$filelocation")

bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter="," --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows --ignore_unknown_values my_project_id:vikrant_test_dataset.{$filename} "$filelocation"

done

Comment: @vikrantrana, you most likely did not have set your project id with gcloud, you can do that as follows: `gcloud config set project your_project_id`. Also, you might need to set up an environment variable as PROJECT_ID = your_project_id (depending on your use case). Please, do not forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: I got the issue.. it was something else..you see I have removed spaces from the actual file location and using same file location variable in the bq as path.. since the original file was still having spaces.. so it was unable to find the path when commands run.. anyway have upvoted your answer. Cheers